# Weyl group and Dynkin diagram

Tags: lie-algebras

Can somebody help me with following questions:
1)Prove that two simple roots in  a Dynkin diagram that are connected by  a 
single edge are in the  same orbit under the Weyl group. 
and
2)For an irreducible root system, prove that all  roots of a particular length 
form a single orbit under the Weyl group.

Comment: Can you show that the two roots corresponding to the vertices of the diagram $A_2$ are in the same orbit?

Comment: No, I dont know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\Phi$ be an irreducible root system, $W$ the Weyl group, and let $\alpha$ be a root. Are you familiar with/can you prove the following?

> **Lemma.** The $W$-orbit of $\alpha$ spans the inner product space.

A direct result of this is that for a second root $\beta$, not every element of $\lbrace\sigma(\alpha):\sigma\in W\rbrace$ can be orthogonal to $\beta$.

So suppose that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ have the same length, then replacing one by a suitable $W$-conjugate, we can assume that they are not orthogonal. So $\langle\alpha,\beta\rangle=\pm 1$. Replacing $\beta$ by its negative $\sigma_\beta(\beta)$ if required, we may assume that $\langle\alpha,\beta\rangle=1$. Then:
$$
(\sigma_\alpha\sigma_\beta\sigma_\alpha)(\beta)=\text{?}
$$